# Shrink unused space in raw image

Tags: kvm, qemu

I have a raw image that includes my Windows disk, including 87Gb of C: ; 80 Gb of unallocated space ; 3 Mo of D: ; 147Gb of unallocated space.

How can I delete the unallocated space from my hypervisor disk loosing as few performance as possible?

My hypervisor is kvm, my system is CentOS 7.5.

Comment: What is the format use ? the hypervysor ?

Comment: Can the VM be stopped?

Comment: The generic solution would be to fill the unallocated space with zeroes within the VM, stop the VM and then create holes in the disk image using `fallocate`.

Comment: Kusalananda's intentions are promising. What is the file system on the hypervisor disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert your raw image to qcow2 using qemu-img. The qcow2 image will only allocate disk as it is needed (sparse).

For example:

```
$ qemu-img convert -O qcow2 myimage.raw myimage.qcow2
```

And then replace the disk image in your VM definition with the qcow2 one.

Comment: This will only sparsify the blocks filled with zeroes. To optimize the process, one would have to zerofill the disk first, something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mountpoint/zerofile; rm -f /mountpoint/zerofile`

Answer (score 0):

The standard utility to deal with this situation is `virt-sparsify`. RAW files do not support sparseness, so you'll need to switch to qcow2 of course.

@tonioc has a more manual approach, but it will definitely also work.

Comment: Sorry, but raw do support thin allocation...